# shiny: pickerIntput choices based on search bar

Tags: r, shiny, spotify

hi i im trying to have the 'choices' in my pickerInput be dependent on what the user types in the search bar above. im using a spotify r package and if you search a certain artist the api returns a table of artists of the similar name and you need to choose which artist you want. anyways i want that table to go into the pickerInput and i can't seem to get it work. [image]

```
    ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "green",
  dashboardHeader(title = "Lyric Prediction"),

  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Overview", tabName = "Overview", icon = icon("search")),
      menuItem("Analysis", tabName = "Analysis", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head( 
      tags$style(HTML(".fa { font-size: 18px; }"))
    ),
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "Overview",
          fluidRow(
            column(12,
              searchInput(
                inputId = "search", label = "Search Artist on Spotify",
                placeholder = "Search",
                btnSearch = icon("search"),
                btnReset = icon("remove"),
                width = "500px"
              )
            ), align = "center"  
            ),

          #HERE - how can i have pickerInput take in the output 
          #of "res" from the server? 


          fluidRow(pickerInput(choices = "res")
          )),
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  #function to take search input 
  #output list of possible artists 
  output$res <- renderTable({         
         #Rspotify
         possibleArtists <- searchArtist(input$search,token=my_oauth)
         possibleArtists <-  as_tibble(possibleArtists)
         myCols <- c("display_name","id")
         colNums <- match(myCols,names(possibleArtists))
         possibleArtists <- possibleArtists %>%
           select(colNums)
         possibleArtists
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `update` method in an `observeEvent` like this:

```
observeEvent(input$search, {
  #Rspotify
  possibleArtists <- searchArtist(input$search,token=my_oauth)
  possibleArtists <-  as_tibble(possibleArtists)
  myCols <- c("display_name","id")
  colNums <- match(myCols,names(possibleArtists))
  possibleArtists <- possibleArtists %>%
    select(colNums)
  updatePickerInput(
    session = session,
    inputId = "picker",
    choices = possibleArtists
  )
}, ignoreInit = TRUE)
```

Full example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "green",

  dashboardHeader(title = "Lyric Prediction"),

  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Overview", tabName = "Overview", icon = icon("search")),
      menuItem("Analysis", tabName = "Analysis", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"))
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(
    tags$head( 
      tags$style(HTML(".fa { font-size: 18px; }"))
    ),
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Overview",
        fluidRow(
          column(12,
                 searchInput(
                   inputId = "search", label = "Search Artist on Spotify",
                   placeholder = "Search",
                   btnSearch = icon("search"),
                   btnReset = icon("remove"),
                   width = "500px"
                 )
          ), align = "center"  
        ),

        pickerInput(inputId = "picker", label = "Choose an artist:", choices = NULL)
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$search, {
    updatePickerInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "picker",
      choices = c("The Beatles", 
                  "The Beatles Recovered Band", 
                  "Yesterday - A Tribute To The Beatles",
                  "The Beatles Revival Band & Orchestra")
    )
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thats fantastic thank you! had no idea observeEvent functions